# Ошибка при переходе с Anaconda 3 на 2?

Tags: python, ide

Столкнулся с неожиданной проблемой, появилась необходимость понизить версию языка, до этого стояла Anaconda 3, решил установить Anaconda 2, но при установке выдает такую ошибку(скриншот ниже), почти в самом конце. Естественно Anaconda 3 была удалена перед установкой 2 версии.Пробовал полностью удалить неудачно установленную Anaconda 2, и потом чистил реестр. Вспомнил что у меня и дефолтный IDE Python 3.7 стоит, думал из-за этого ошибка, удалил короче все что связано с Python, почистил реестр, установил все по новой, версию 2.7 и опять ошибка. Почитал в гугле, русских букв в пути к анаконде нет, имя пользователя на английском написано. Не понимаю где может быть ошибка. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя последнюю версию Anaconda можно установить несколько виртуальных окружений (VirtualEnv's) для различных версий Python:

1. установить актуальную (последнюю) версию Anaconda
2. создать несколько виртуальных окружений:

   ```
   conda create -n py36 python=3.6
   conda create -n py35 python=3.5
   conda create -n py27 python=2.7
   ```
3. запускать скрипты/iPython/Jupyter/python из соответствующего окружения
4. или активизировать нужное окружение перед запуском:

   ```
   activate py27
   ```

Вот пример моих окружений (VirtualEnv's):

```
C:\> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0
ml                       C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\ml
py27                     C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py27
py36                     C:\Users\Max\Anaconda3_5.0\envs\py36
```

Пример запуска iPython для Python 2.7:

```
C:\Users\Max>activate py27

(py27) C:\Users\Max>ipython
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Nov  8 2017, 13:40:45) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помог Ваш ответ, единственное возникает ошибка при попытки запуска notebook или того же самого ipython, ругается на то что это не является командой..

Comment: @Mr.Flatman, скорее всего `ipython` и `jupyter` надо установить для всех окружений: `conda install ipython jupyter -n py27 -y`

Comment: спасибо, разобрался, я что-то понадеялся что он сам все поставит, но не там то было.. использовал команду conda `install -n <имя окружения> <пакет>(в моем случаи ipython notebook)`